# Extracting information from Esri Grid Format (ADF) file using R?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, r, convert, esri-grid-format

I have an adf file that has a variety of "attribute" or field layers, and I am trying to extract one layer from that adf file, and convert it to a tiff image for further processing in python. Here is an overview of what the data looks like from R:

```
> r1
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 7272, 10970, 79773840  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 300, 300  (x, y)
extent      : 911643, 4202643, 234254.4, 2415854  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=lcc +lat_1=17.5 +lat_2=29.5 +lat_0=12 +lon_0=-102    +x_0=2500000 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
names       : modef_proj1 
values      : 1, 9374  (min, max)
attributes  :
           ID Rowid COUNT    Hio     NIV_Hio
   from:    1     0    31 0.0001   Muy Bajo
   to  : 9374  8491     1 0.9374   Muy Alto
```

Does anyone know an easy way to extract the Hio attribute layer.m?

When I convert the adf file to a tiff I always only extract the Rowid column. I am comfortable using ArcGIS, R, Python, or GDAL. But, I am not succeeding in converting this file format.

Comment: It sounds like what you may have is an Esri Grid Raster file.

Comment: @PolyGeo that sounds right -- do you know how to get the specified attribute field out of it?

Comment: I have not worked with that format for a long time but there are 60 other Q&As here that may provide some insight: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/esri-grid-format  Another term to look for is "raster attribute table" because that is where those values appear to be sitting.